# Java and OpenCV: Calculate Median / Mean / Stdev value of MAT (Gray-Image)

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, mat

I've got an image as grayscale image using

```
Mat m = Highgui.imread(path, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

in Java and now I want to calculate the median value, the mean value and the standard deviation. I'n new to this and I simply don't know how to find out the calculations and stuff... Tried 2 hours of googeling, please give me some basic advise on how to do research on this. I tried keywords like "mean value java opencv" and found this:

[http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#meanStdDev](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#meanStdDev%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble%29)

I'm now doing this:

```
MatOfDouble mu = new MatOfDouble();
MatOfDouble sigma = new MatOfDouble();
Core.meanStdDev(m, mu, sigma);
```

But HOW the hell to access the mean/stdev value as a double? Tried things like

```
double d = mu.get(0,0)
```

but there's something wrong. I can't find it out by reading the OpenCV Java docs myself unfortunately as I don't know what to look for/at.

I need mean/stdev to calculate the thresholds for the canny filter...
Thanks so far in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
double d = mu.get(0,0)[0]
```

`mu.get(0,0)` returns a `double[]`, so you can just get the first element - it's equivalent to the C++ version of:

```
mu.val[0]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: is that double d is median? @Chewxy

Comment: mu is typically the symbol for the mean

Comment: Note: This only gives an accurate answer for grayscale images. For color images you'll need to take the average of all the channels. Ex. `double totalMu = (mu.get(0,0)[0] + mu.get(1,0)[0] + mu.get(2,0)[0]) / 3.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corresponding code for a 3 channel color image.I've used Lab color space.It will work with BGR as well...

```
//compute color statistics for the source image
    List<Mat> labsrc = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(src, labsrc);


    MatOfDouble meansrc= new MatOfDouble();
    MatOfDouble stdsrc= new MatOfDouble();

    Core.meanStdDev(src, meansrc, stdsrc);

    Log.d("meansrc",meansrc.dump() );

    Log.d("meanval1", String.valueOf(meansrc.get(0,0)[0]));
    Log.d("meanval2", String.valueOf(meansrc.get(1,0)[0]));
    Log.d("meanval3", String.valueOf(meansrc.get(2,0)[0]));

    double lMeanSrc = meansrc.get(0,0)[0];
    double aMeanSrc = meansrc.get(1,0)[0];
    double bMeanSrc = meansrc.get(2,0)[0];

    double lStdSrc = stdsrc.get(0,0)[0];
    double aStdSrc = stdsrc.get(1,0)[0];
    double bStdSrc = stdsrc.get(2,0)[0];
```

Comment: Works fine thanks, but you don't need the first two lines since labsrc is never used.